# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una subconsulta en una vista en Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, subconsultas

quiero desplegar un listado en la Vista index de Productos, por lo cual cada producto pertenece a una marca, los datos de las marcas los tengo en otra tabla por lo que en cada ciclo del foreach dentro de la vista Index( donde quiero q se despliegue) hace la subconsulta al controlador enviandole la variable , pero me aparece vacio, esa es la primer pregunta la segunda es, como mostrar la variable de la subconsulta para las marcas en la vista de Index, como devolverla? espero haberme explicado dejo el codigo.

Dejo el código para que se entienda mejor, gracias!
**código de la vista Index **

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($productos as $producto)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
            
            <td>{{ $nombreMarcas->nombreMarca }} </td>
            <td>{{ $producto->nombre }}</td>
            <td> {{ $producto->contenido }} {{ $producto->unidad }}</td>
            <td>{{ $producto->entrada }}</td>
            <td>{{ $producto->precio }}</td>
            <td>
            <a href="{{ url('/productos/'.$producto->id.'/edit') }}" class="btn btn-warning">
        
            Editar 
            </a>
            <form method="post" action="{{ url('/productos/'.$producto->id) }}" style="display:inline">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            {{method_field('DELETE')}}
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('¿Borrar?');">Borrar</button>
                
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach    
    </tbody>
```

**Código del Controlador **

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        
        $nombreMarcas=Marcas::select('nombreMarca')->where('idMarca', '$producto->idMarca')->get();
        dd($nombreMarcas);
        $marcas=Marcas::select(['idMarca','nombreMarca'])->get();
        $datos['productos']=Productos::paginate(1);
        return view('productos.index',$datos, compact('marcas'),compact('nombreMarcas'));
    }
```

**Código de Modelo de Marcas**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Marcas extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Comment: ¿Tienes definida la relación con Producto en el model Marca?

Comment: estoy usando en el controlador de Productos el modelo de Marcas:                use App\Models\Marcas;

Comment: Ok, no hay problema con usar el modelo Marcas en el controlador de Productos. Me refiero a la [relaciones entre los modelos](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships), ya que facilitaría mucho usarlas para hacer la consulta en el controlador. Por favor edita la pregunta agregando el código del modelo Marcas.

Comment: Listo, no tengo relaciones entre los modelos

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo más recomendable ahí, es definir la relación entre el modelo Marcas y el modelo Productos, para luego usarla en la consulta.

Entonces, asumiendo que una Marca tiene muchos Productos, la relación a definir sería [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

> Una relación de uno a muchos se utiliza para definir relaciones en las que un único modelo es el padre de uno o más modelos secundarios. Por ejemplo, una marca puede tener una cantidad "infinita" de productos. Como todas las demás relaciones de Eloquent, las relaciones de uno a muchos se definen definiendo un método en su modelo de Eloquent:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Marcas extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    /**
    * Obtener los productos de la marca.
    */
    public function productos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Productos::class, 'marca_id'); // cambia marca_id por el nombre la llave foránea que tengas en la tabla productos
    }
}
```

> Recuerde, Eloquent determinará automáticamente la columna de llave foránea adecuada para el modelo de Productos. Por convención, Eloquent tomará el nombre en "snake_case" del modelo padre y lo agregará como sufijo `_id`. Entonces, en este ejemplo, Eloquent asumirá que la columna de clave externa en el modelo Productos es `marcas_id`.

> Una vez definido el método de relación, podemos acceder a la colección de productos relacionados accediendo a la propiedad `productos`.

```
$productos = Marcas::find(1)->productos;
```

Luego, podemos usar [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) para reducir la operación a solo dos consultas. Al crear una consulta, puede especificar qué relaciones deben cargarse con eager load utilizando el método `with`:

```
public function index()
{
    $marcas = Marcas::with('productos')->get();
    return view('productos.index', compact('marcas'));
}
```

Y finalmente hacer un loop sobre las marcas y otro loop anidado sobre los productos de cada marca:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($marcas as $marca)
        @foreach($marca->productos as $producto)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $marca->nombreMarca }} </td>
                <td>{{ $producto->nombre }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach    
    @endforeach    
</tbody>
```

---

Otra forma, sería declarando la inversa de la relación en el modelo Productos [One To Many (Inverse) / Belongs To](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Productos extends Model
{
    /**
     * Obtener la marca a la que pertenece el producto.
     */
    public function marca()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Marcas::class, 'marca_id');
    }
}
```

Y en el controlador, consultar el modelo Productos, cargando su Marca relacionada:

```
public function index()
{
    $productos = Productos::with('marca')->paginate(10);
    return view('productos.index', compact('productos'));
}
```

Y en la vista hacer un sólo loop sobre los productos, accediendo a la relación marca para mostrar su nombre:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($productos as $producto)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $producto->marca->nombreMarca }} </td>
            <td>{{ $producto->nombre }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach  
</tbody>
```

Comment: Te agradezco, me funcionó muy bien